# How to get Pycharm's coverage tool to work with monkey patching?

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, code-coverage, pytest

```
def test_do_something():
    import custom_pandas_methods # patches collapse into pd.DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a': [1,2,3],
        'b': [1,2,3],
    })
    assert df.collapse('a') == 5
```

I'm running the above test in Pycharm using pytest (with the --cov option).  It works fine when run without Pycharm's coverage tool.

However, when I "run with coverage", the test fails i.e.,

```
FPatching collapse into pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
E       RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

The RuntimeError occurs in collapse.py, which contains the collapse method.  Why would I get such an error?

Comment: which version of pandas are you using. one of Pandas version had this issue

Comment: `pandas==0.23.4`

Comment: Why monkeypatch dataframe? Just write a function that takes a dataframe as an argument.

Comment: @NedBatchelder, I rewrote the test using a simple function and I get the same result i.e., Pycharm "test" works; Pycharm "test with coverage" fails.  Apparently monkey patching is NOT the issue here; however, I'm still struggling to understand how one passes and the other fails.  (To answer your question: I'm building a Stata port that uses \_\_getattr\_\_ to  search through the PYTHONPATH in order to find a module that contains a function of the same name and then I monkey patch that into pd.DataFrame.  I find pandas alone to be too verbose for on-the-fly data analysis.)